# LetsEncrypt certbot multiple renew-hooks

Tags: lets-encrypt

I'm automating an SSL certificate renewal from LetsEncrypt's certbot. The actual renewal is working, but I need to automate restarting services so that they load the renewed certificates. I was wondering if you can use multiple `--renew-hook` parameters within the cronjob for `letsencrypt renew`?

**How to automate restarting services upon certificate renewal?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple --renew-hook statements. also use the -q flag so it emails you a blank notification until a renewal actually does occur. It also does not restart any of your services until a renewal occurs. This also attaches the log file to the email if you so desire.

I have a cron that runs a bash daily.

Inside my bash (certbotrenew.sh) is simply this

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/certbot
sudo ./certbot-auto renew --renew-hook "service postfix reload" --renew-hook "service dovecot restart" --renew-hook "service apache2 reload" -q >> /var/log/certbot-renew.log | mail -s "CERTBOT Renewals" me@myemail.com  < /var/log/certbot-renew.log
exit 0
```

and my cron is

```
00 20 * * 1 /bin/certbotrenew.sh
```

Some people question why I send an email regardless of if nothing happened, I just always like to know my daily crons are running.

Comment: It looks like the default package manager for Ubuntu 16.04 carries an old version of Certbot that doesn't accept `--renew-hook` arguments.

Comment: Yes the repo has a very old version of Let's Encrypt, which has been renamed to certbot anyway last year. You can simply uninstall the repo version and then simply `mkdir /opt/certbot` and then `cd /opt/certbot` and then `sudo wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto` then just run your certbot-auto command lines from there. If memory serves me correct the version in the Ubuntu repo is v0.4 of let's encrypt. Certbot is now at 0.11.

Comment: @MitchellK - rather than getting a daily cron email, how about a cron reporting service like https://IsItWorking.info (mine). Your cron script can check in each time it runs successfully. If it doesn't check in, then the service alerts you. (Possibly in addition to an email)

Comment: Can you actually use multiple renew hook commands? I don't think so and there is [an issue](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5076) for this.

Comment: so the `--renew-hook` runs only if the certificate is about to expired and was renewed, correct?

Comment: @W.M. Yes, that is correct. When you run it on the command line without the ```--force-renew``` option, you will see ```No renewals were attempted.
No hooks were run.``` at the end of the output

Comment: Note: On newer (early 2023) versions, you cannot use multiple --pre-hook (or others hooks). Each new directive of the same name will overwrite the previous one. But you can put the directive once, and then list multiple scripts, space-separated and encapsulated by double-quotes. Example: --pre-hook "script1 script2 script3"

Answer (score 40):

Not sure if that's for newer versions only or not, but hope someone will find it useful.
When you have at least 1 domain added, certbot will create "renewal-hooks" dir with 3 subdirs "deploy", "post", "pre".

If you will put any script into "post" folder, that will be executed after renewal automatically. 
Don't forget to make it executable by adding +x to the script.

I'm using just one "001-restart-nginx.sh" with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ssl certs updated" && service nginx restart
```

`/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/post/001-restart-nginx.sh`

This way you don't have to manually supply `--post-hook` params with certain instructions at all.

On actual renewal process you will see something like this:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain-name>/fullchain.pem (success)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Running post-hook command: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/post/001-restart-nginx.sh
Output from post-hook command 001-restart-nginx.sh:
ssl certs updated
```

Comment: It's better to use `nginx reload` as restart will lead to unnecessary downtime.

Answer (score 14):

You can also set hooks (and others options if you like) as global options in the file `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini` ([see documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#configuration-file)) like this:

```
# Global config for letsencrypt runs
#
# Note that these options apply automatically to all use of Certbot for
# obtaining or renewing certificates, so options specific to a single
# certificate on a system with several certificates should not be placed
# here.

renew-hook = service postfix reload
post-hook = service nginx reload
```

You must create the file first on most systems. Letsencrypt comes without.

You can also create certificate specific version in every `renewal` folder if you don't like to go global.

Comment: Yes that works, but the `--renew-hook` suggestion in the other answer is preferred.  When you run the command with `--renew-hook`, that makes it add the hook info to the domain in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal, so the hook will get run each time automatically.  That's a preferred solution rather than editing /etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini directly.

Answer (score 7):

From what I saw from the fresh installation in Ubuntu 16.04 of CertBot, it creates a cron job:

```
# /etc/cron.d/certbot: crontab entries for the certbot package
#
# Upstream recommends attempting renewal twice a day
#
# Eventually, this will be an opportunity to validate certificates haven't been revoked, etc.  Renewal will only occur if expiration is within
# 30 days.
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew --pre-hook 
'/bin/run-parts /etc/letsencrypt/pre-hook.d/' --post-hook '/bin/run-parts /etc/letsencrypt/post-hook.d/' --renew-hook '/bin/run-parts
/etc/letsencrypt/renew-hook.d/'
```

So it executes `run-parts` on many directories, including `/etc/letsencrypt/renew-hook.d/`

You just need to add an executable file in any of those hook directories (pick the one you need).

As an example, in my `renew-hook.d` I created a file `restart-nginx` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

As a note: You can know what files will be called by `run-parts` using the `--test` option. (Example `run-parts --test /etc/letsencrypt/renew-hook.d/`

Comment: They actually changed the certbot cronjob to no longer include those run-parts parameters anymore. Recommended way to accomplish the same now is to create a `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini` and specify the hook parameters in there, see
https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1706#issuecomment-302774426

Comment: Yes, either in a cli.ini, or the in `[renewalparams]` area in each `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf` file if you don't want global. I have a mix of route53 and standalone, so I prefer to edit each renewal config file. You do not need a cli.ini in each renew area. Just edit the renew file.

Answer (score 5):

The latest recommended method for running hook scripts is from `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini`. If the file is not present you can create it yourself. Another thing is that you should use `--deploy-hook` instead `--renew-hook`. --renew-hook is still present but will be getting phased out since it's not even mentioned in the latest documentation.

So just create `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini` if it doesn't exist and add the following line:

```
deploy-hook = "service postfix reload ; service dovecot restart ; service apache2 reload"
```

to reload those particular services.

Comment: Or, in [renewalparams] area in each `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf` file if you don't want global ini.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a place that controls certbot running (on ubuntu 16.04 + nginx — settings files bellow)

1) systemd timer

run commnad: `sudo systemctl list-timers`

and see output:

```
Sun 2018-07-08 00:46:59 EEST 7h left Sat 2018-07-07 12:36:26 EEST 4h 51min ago certbot.timer certbot.service
```

then

2)

check file that controls time when systemctl run Certbot

```
/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/certbot.timer
```

this is the symbolic link for

```
/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer
```

Pay attention to this lines that defines times + random seconds (set a random time for purpose not to stress letsencrypt servers)

```
OnCalendar=--* 00,12:00:00

RandomizedDelaySec=3600
```

Answer (score 0):

### For CentOS and Amazon Linux (and probably other types of Linux):

When you install *certbot* via yum, yum creates two services which keep your certificates up to date:

```
# systemctl list-unit-files | grep cert
certbot-renew.service                         static
certbot-renew.timer                           enabled
```

Once you enable the *timer* service, it runs periodically, invoking the *renew* service as needed.

The package installer also creates the template file `/etc/sysconfig/certbot` (below).  This file is executed when the above `certbot-renew` service runs.  It contains a stanza designed to run **once for each successfully renewed certificate**.  This is the cleanest way I know of to tell your web server to acquire certificates, as the *HOOK* command does not run unnecessarily.  For my Apache installation, I configure this stanza as follows:

```
# Command to be run in a shell once for each
# successfully renewed certificate. For this command,
# the shell variable $RENEWED_LINEAGE will point to the
# config live subdirectory containing the new certs and
# keys; the shell variable $RENEWED_DOMAINS will contain
# a space-delimited list of renewed cert domains
#
# An example to run a script to alert each cert would be:
# DEPLOY_HOOK="--deploy-hook /usr/local/bin/cert-notifier.sh"
DEPLOY_HOOK="--deploy-hook 'systemctl reload httpd'"
```