# Optimal script to copy a Letsencrypt certificate everytime it renews to another directory on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, cron, lets-encrypt

My letsencrypt certificate renews every 60 days or so and when it does my application crashes which is stored on same server in opt directory
I would like to create a cronjob and/or script which executes everytime the certificate is renewed.  Is there a command or list of commands which can run which scans the directory for the update and if there is to copy it to another folder on my server?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LetsEncrypt certbot multiple renew-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300579/letsencrypt-certbot-multiple-renew-hooks)

Comment: In the live / folder directory the symlinks are there which point to the new files as they are updated every 2 months or whatever - so I basically can use the readlink command with the -f switch which will allow the path to be available but I need to be able to create a script which stores this path and then copies the new file if it changes .  I havent been able to logically setup a script that does that as of yet